# Top Menu showing as Plain text before page load

Tags: menus

On loading the [website](http://teamdrivenrealestate.com/) of mine, it is showing the plain text of menu for a while and thereafter it is working fine. This is really a strange issue for me.

I tried solving using [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plain-text-menu-loading-before-theme) WordPress post, but this doesn't solve my issue.

Can you guys please help?

Comment: Look at your html. You have 134 lines of rubbish before the doctype. There's something really wrong with your theme.

Comment: I knew about that. It was there from a long time. But the site was working properly. It is not making any harm. This issue prevails from 3 - 4 days.

Comment: It's that code that is showing, possibly because some other tweak to your site or the server has caused the rest to load slower. You can go search for that tweak or remove the root cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You have to revise and reorder your code structure.**

Your site loads 27 render-blocking javascript files and 33 CSS files before the content above the fold. Also you load some plugin content before the styles are applied.

Try to defer the blocking CSS and JS. Load everything early that is needed to display the first visible content (=above the fold) and load anything else after this.

In your case you could try to locate jquery, navigation and the form plugin scripts in the `<head>` and locate the sliders scripts in the footer. If there are no problems locate jquery and dependent scripts in the footer using [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).  Generally load CSS in the `<head>` and JS before `</body>`.

This [review](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fteamdrivenrealestate.com%2F) and [this](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/160519_Y4_1d3544a4cbe7ed69ed2d2bb8b2d8e560/1/details/) waterfall chart are  showing the loading sequences of your site. Take a look in the details on how to solve the several issues.

Additionally you should:

- Declare a doctype in the document head
- Use a caching Plugin such as [Autoptimize](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/) or [W3TC](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/)

I guess your problems result from wrong load order.

You can use these tools to analyze your site:

- http://www.webpagetest.org/
- https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/
- http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/
- https://gtmetrix.com/

They do basically the same with little differences in reviews.